# when i pass static data it will be store data successfull.when i pass dynamic it will not store data.how to pass dynamic data

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

when i passed static it will be succefull stored in data base. when i pass dynamic data it will not stored in database.in my view form id is **signupform** which have 5 fields.

**here is my .js file**

```
$(document).on("submit","#signupform",function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();

    //var view_id=$("#id_hid").val();
    //alert(view_id);
    console.log($('#signupform').serialize());
    var data = {'username' : 'username' , 'password' : 'password' , 'email' : 'email' , 'mobileno' : 'mobileno' , 'address' : 'address' };
    data = $('#signupform').serialize() + '&' + $.param(data);

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:data,//$('#signupform').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        url:"../welcome/add",       
        success:function(data){
            //var json=$.parseJSON(data);
            //$('#signupform').html(response);
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

** Here is my controller file**

```
public function add(){
    $data=array();
    $postData=array();

    //prepare post data
    $postData = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'mobileno' => $this->input->post('mobileno'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address')
    );  


    //print_r($postData);

    //insert post data

    $insert = $this->home_model->insert_form($postData);
    $data['msg']= "data insert successfully";
    echo json_encode($data['msg']);
}
```

**Here is my model file**

```
function insert_form($data){

    $insert=$this->db->insert('emp',$data);
    if($insert){
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    echo  json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to post a string data, you can remove `dataType: "JSON"`

Or you can use this method

```
$(document).on('submit', '#signupform', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = {username: 'username', password: 'password', email: 'email', mobileno: 'mobileno', address: 'address'};
  data = Object.assign({}, $('#signupform').serializeArray()[0], data);
  console.log(data);

  $.post('your backend url', data, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  })
})
```

Comment: for this form data will not store i want to store form data.only filed name will store.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define the `data` object. The `serialize()` method would do that for you. But, because you are making a POST you should use `serializeArray()` instead. `serialize()` is geared toward GET requests.

```
$(document).on("submit","#signupform",function(e){ 
    var data;
    e.preventDefault();
    data = $('#signupform').serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:data,
        dataType: "JSON",
        url:"../welcome/add",       
        success:function(data){
            //data is an object. If you want the text returned use data.msg
            //$('#some-message-div').text(data.msg);
            console.log(data); //an object with one property - 'msg'
        }
    });
});
```

The controller method can be simplified a lot. Because the field names exactly match the table column names there is no need to build the `$postData` array. The posted data already has that exact structure. `$this->input->post()` will return what you need.

```
public function add()
{
    //insert post data
    if($this->home_model->insert_form($this->input->post()))
    {
        $data['msg'] = "data insert successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        $data['msg'] = "insert failed";
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

The model can be much cleaner.

```
function insert_form($data)
{
    if($this->db->insert('emp', $data))
    {
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    //don't need else when the if condition calls return
    return false;
}
```

The line `echo json_encode($data);` served no purpose. The way it was coded that line never executed - both the if and else blocks returned. Even if it did execute, it's the wrong thing for a model to do.